# Unwanted process is running on VM and consuming 98% CPU consistently

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I could see one of the process running on VM and consuming 98% CPU consistently, it auto starts if i kill the same. 
Process details is as below:

```
root      3740     1 98 11:00 ?        00:49:34 /var/tmp/sustes -c /var/tmp/wm.conf
```

and the conf file is something as below,

some other details +

```
"api": {
    "port": 123,                             // port for the miner API https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig/wiki/API
    "access-token": 111,                  // access token for API
    "worker-id": 111                      // custom worker-id for API
}
```

Please help me out to identify about the same and how to remove that from server.

Comment: You have a Monero miner running on your server that you don't know about...? Hmm.

Comment: How I can remove that ?

Comment: You've been hacked. Hacking triage is reinstall if you're not 100% sure what the attack vector was, and what was done.

Comment: Nuke the whole site from orbit. It's the only way to be sure.